# finiteness of k-th moment implies finiteness of lower moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint distribution $F(x,y)$, with $E[X]=\mu_X$.

(*) Prove that if $E[X^4] < \infty$ then $E[(X-\mu_X)^4]<\infty$

---

It seems obvious but I'm not convinced. Expanding the polynomial we get

$E[(X-\mu_X)^4] = E[(X^4-\mu_X X^3 +\mu_X^2 X^2 - \mu_X^3X +  \mu_X^4]$

Now we just need to prove that $E[X^3] < \infty$ and $E[X^2] < \infty$

---

In a measure-theoretic probability book i found the following theorem:

if k>0 and $E[X^k]<\infty $ then $E[X^j]<\infty $ for all $0<j<k$

Proof of the theorem is:

(**) $\rVert X \lVert_j \leq\rVert X \lVert_k$  for $0<j<k$

---

I have two questions:

1. Is there an easier way to prove (*)? (without doing the expansion perhaps?)
2. In the proof for (**) is $\rVert X \lVert_j = \rvert \int_{x \in A} \lvert x \lvert^j dx \vert^{1/j} $ where A is all the possible values that random variable X can take? If it's not, then what is it? And if it is, then how does that prove the finiteness of lower order moments?

Comment: To prove $(\ast)$, use $$(X-\mu)^4\leqslant2^3\cdot(X^4+\mu^4)$$To prove $(\ast\ast)$, use, for every $j<k$,  $$|x|^j\leqslant1+|x|^k$$

Answer (score 3):

1) I would use the inequality 
$$|a-b|^4\leq (|a|+|b|)^4\leq 2^3(|a|^4+|b|^4)$$
which follows from the triangle inequality and from applying twice $(x+y)^2\leq 2(x^2+y^2)$. Now the claim follows applying 2).

2) Set
$$\|X\|_j=\left(\int |x|^j d\mathbb{P}_X(x)\right)^{\frac1j}.$$
where $\mathbb{P}_X$ is the law of the random variable. Then the inequality $\|X\|_j\le\|X\|_k$ for $j\leq k$ follows from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) $$\|fg\|_{1}\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_q$$
for $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, applied with $f=|x|^j$, $g=1$, $p=\frac kj$ (and the value of $q$ follows).